# Regex to select parenthesis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Working on a regex pattern to sanitize HTML output and remove any special characters. My thought is to write a regex listing all the characters I want to keep and remove everything else rather then trying to account for all special characters in the pattern.

My current pattern:

```
/[^0-9A-Za-z,=": ?'`&;>|<!.\-\/]/
```

It's working great, except it is removing parenthesis () which I'd like to keep. I can't seem to escape them correctly when adding to my pattern. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/[^0-9A-Za-z,=": ?'`&;>|<!.\-\/()]/
```

Inside range blocks "[]", different escape rules apply.

Comment: Although escaping the `(`- and `)`'s: `/[^0-9A-Za-z,=": ?'\`&;>|<!.\-\/\(\)]/`, will also work (although not needed, as you mentioned). Makes me wonder _how_ the OP was escaping them...

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) method built in to Rails.

Comment: Upvoting this. It's a well tested method. Trying to build your own regex will work in many cases, but not in all. For example, someone could put in: <scri<script>pt>. Your removal of the middle script tag would result in another script tag being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.delete( %q{^a-zA-Z1-9,=:"`&;>|<!.-/ ()'} )
# or with another delimiter (*):
str.delete( %q*^a-zA-Z1-9,=:"`&;>|<!.-/ ()'* )
```

String.delete takes one or more strings as argument (and negates them with '^', just like a regex). With the %q{string} syntax you don have to worry about escaping.

Comment: You still have to worry about escaping right? Just not escaping forward slashes. If he wanted to have { } in his expression he'd need to escape it correct?

Comment: @YGomez Yes. But you can choose the delimiter yourself. Updating answer.